# Symfony 2 CMF - Installing cmf sandbox

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-cmf

I try to install smf-sandbox from git https://github.com/symfony-cmf/cmf-sandbox

But I got error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\RoutingBundle\Admin\Extension\FrontendLinkExtension::__construct() must be an instance  of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Translation\Translator, instance of Symfony\Component\Translation\LoggingTranslator given, called in \cmf\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 5251 and defined

I start useing SF CMF so I don't know where I have to search.
Someone can help me?

I tried to find some solution on Internet but I can't find anything.

EDIT:
That error shows when I try to clear cache.

Comment: why the error comes from cache?? use symfony console to clear cache. and install needed bundles (seems like errors on Translation bundle.) and use this page to start http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/index.html

Comment: That error shows when I try to clear cache.

Comment: Try to clear the cache manually : from your project's root directory, run `rm -rf app/cache/* app/logs/*`

Answer (score 3):

In deed `translator` service before Symfony 2.6 was an alias for `translator.default`, unfortunately this has changed in Symfony 2.6 with the addition of LoggingTranslator feature. (You can verify this by running `php app/console container:debug`)

If the code **is not typehinted correctly**, than you need to use the `translator.default` service explicitly, the `translator` service may cause errors.

See [this Github issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12795) for complete internals.

Answer (score 1):

You can either downgrade symfony/symfony to 2.5.* or upgrade symfony-cmf/routing-bundle to dev-master:

in composer.json

`"require": {
    // to downgrade symfony: "symfony/symfony": "2.5.*", // OR
    "symfony-cmf/routing-bundle": "dev-master@dev",      //  upgrade CmfRoutingBundle
}`

Followed by:

`$ composer update symfony-cmf/routing-bundle`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that this new extension was expecting a concrete class instead of an interface, which became a problem in Symfony 2.6. This was fixed last week and i just released version 1.3.3 of the RoutingBundle now.
You can simply `composer update symfony-cmf/routing-bundle` without needing to change your version constraint (assuming you require 1.3.*).